# How do I use GreenDao LazyList correct for huge amount of data + Sort and Filtering

Tags: java, android, sqlite, paging, greendao

I'm trying to implement paging in android listview.

Background: I download around ~60k datasets via webservice and save them into a SQLite db using GreenDao. Now i want to access this 60k rows in a ListView and select some (0-10). The selected items are send to another ListView containing only the selection. The db entries are ~3 MB for all 60k entries.

Whats already implemented:

- SQLite DB
- DAOs
- ListViews
- Adapters
- Transferlogic Data ListView --> Selected Data ListView

The ListView is shown in a DialogFragment. I came up with the idea of using the GreenDao LazyList class, because this list can loaded single items without directly loading all items.

Because LazyList doesn't allow changes to the list (remove, add, clear)

I did the following:
The ListView has an Adapter class that uses a java.util.List in the DialogFragment I query for the LazyList (get all) or use an EditText to apply a like clause.

The first time I query the 60k entries I load the first 50 items into the adapter and display them in the ListView. I wan't to use a navigation bar to change the items later.

I want the EditText to work directly while the user is typing so i added a TextChangeListener.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(lazyList != null) {
                if(!lazyList.isClosed()) {
                    lazyList.close();
                    lazyList = null;
                }
            }

            if(s.length() <= 1) {
                QueryBuilder qb = session.getCodeSystemDao().queryBuilder();
                lazyList = qb.listLazyUncached();
                resetListView();
            }
            else {
                QueryBuilder qb = session.getCodeSystemDao().queryBuilder();
                qb.where(DataDao.Properties.Value.like("%"+s.toString()+"%"));
                lazyList = qb.listLazyUncached();
                resetListView();
            }
        }
    });
```

**The problem is: while only typing 1-4 characters a list won't show because the cursor memory is full see Log:**

```
W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 48 bytes, free space 19 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
```

I could use the GC after closing the list but using GC directly in java is a pain. Is there a better way to do this? (actually I tried that once and didn't work).

I need the the values to be searchable (way to many entries) and it must be sortable.

If I click on a button "sort alphabetically" it does use both (edittext [for like] and ORDER) in a GreenDAO QueryBuilder to load a new lazylist (like the textwatcher + order clause).

Comment: Could you share your fix?

Comment: @nAkhmedov Instead of using LazyList i now simply use a normal list with paging. Use `QueryBuilder qb = yourSession.getYourDao().queryBuilder()` like normal and add limit and offset `qb.limit(50)` `qb.offset(100)` this would return you entries from 101 to 150 from your db. Limit limits the number of returned elements und offset starts from a specific entry. To calculate values for offset just query the `count()` befor the entries so you can always check that you're inbound.
Paging can be different for every approach so you should check what you can use with your layout.

Comment: Thank you for yr response! LazyList is a bad idea for paging?

Comment: @nAkhmedov the question is why do you want to use it? It just bloats up your memory usage it consumes less memory if you just load 100 entries and if you want to see the next 100 remove the 100 old entries and load the new ones. So you use less RAM. If you use LazyList, dummy entries are generated into that list wich occupie much more space. You may load the real entries later while viewing them with LazyList but that means the list grows larger and it won't remove entries you don't need to see right now. In Android you normaly have around 50 MB RAM per app (without largHeap).

Comment: The LazyList just sits on top of a cursor and doesn't load everything into memory.

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoCore/src/main/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/query/LazyList.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not use LazyList here. Paging is usually done with a query using LIMIT and OFFSET parameters.

Check the "Limit, Offset, and Pagination" section here: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/

Comment: Yeah after trying different approaches I thought about that too and searched the sqlite doc. I didn't saw that small paragraph in the greendao doc when I was reading it the first time. I just wanted to use the LazyList for paging because I thought it wont load all data so it isn't that big but it actually does allocate alle memory for all but not yet accessed objects. Thanks for the hint!